# How should I test a multiuser web app (meteor)?

Tags: meteor, headless, multi-user, headless-browser

What headless browser or similar tool could I use to do end-to-end testing on a multiuser web app? Requirements:

- javascript, python, or ruby for scripting; preferably js.
- MUST be able to run multiple browsers simultaneously, with their separate cookies, etc. (so phantomjs/casperjs is out).
- full-featured js support in-browser, enough to handle a complex meteor.js app (which apparently zombie.js ???and?ghost.py??? doesn't have.
- Ideally, you would have done something like this yourself, as the fact that phantomjs bleeds state across instances is NOT documented.
- If the only way to do this is to actually run multiple instances of node (or python or whatever) then so be it, but ideally all the browsers could run from a single script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/) wich is a testing framework for meteor.

From the documentation, you can test run tests with client/server interactions:

```
test('using both client and the server', function(done, server, client) {
// Your test
```

And you can even have multiple (and theoretically unlimited) clients:

```
function(done, server, c1, c2, c3, c4) {
```

Concerning your cookie issue, Laika use `phantomjs` but I don't know if it uses one different instance for each client.

Comment: Meteor does not use cookier rather uses local storage. Laika can can run upto 3 client with 3 diff users. see here for more: https://github.com/arunoda/laika/issues/4